# Firebase: Como pasar una referencia a la BD entre actividades

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una actividad principal (ActivityMain) donde me conecto a una Base de Datos Firebase.

Lo que quisiera hacer es pasar la conexión a otra actividad, y de esta forma no tener que repetir la conexión en la nueva actividad.

He visto que al crear el `Intent` no hay un `putExtra` que permita añadirle la referencia.

¿Como se podría pasar la conexión a la BD Firebase entre actividades?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres "arrastrar" la conexión de un sitio a otro? No me parece una buena idea. Esa conexión seguirá activa ¿por qué motivo? Si tienes un millón de usuarios, con esa práctica vas a mantener vivas un millón de conexiones. No quiero estar ahí cuando llegue la factura. Y si es un plan gratuito, no sé si sabes que cuando excedes el límite la App se cae durante todo lo que resta del mes. Lo correcto sería leer los datos, llenar un objeto con ellos y pasar ese objeto a la otra actividad. Cuidado con arrastrar conexiones activas de Firebase. Estamos ante otro concepto de manejo de datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.
Aún no tengo claro como funcionan las sesiones en Firebase.
Yo creía que cuando pasas de una actividad a otro se pierde la sesión, y por eso la vuelvo a crear en cada actividad, y para evitarlo pensaba en crearla en la actividad principal y luego ir pasandola de actividad en actividad.
¿Cómo sería la forma más correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Lo más correcto es conectar a Firebase allí donde lo necesites, no ir pasando una conexión de un lado para otro. No sé lo que hace tu aplicación realmente pero no me parece una buena idea lo que planteas. ¿Acaso la App trabaja 100% con Firebase para todo? ¿No hay más cosas que hace la App sin tener que usar Firebase?¿Qué es lo que justifica que haya que conectar a Firebase desde la Actividad principal y querer mantener viva esa conexión? Si necesitas pasar datos tomados de Firebase de una Actividad a otra lo correcto sería tomar los datos llenar un objeto con ellos, cerrar Firebase y pasar ...

Comment: ... el objeto a la otra actividad. A no ser que lo haga tu App es compartir datos que cambian constantemente y esos cambios tengan que ser reflejados en todo momento en tiempo real. De ser así, ¿qué justificaría un cambio de actividad basado en los mismos datos, por qué no se gestiona todo en la misma actividad? Como podrás comprender, todo depende del contexto y de lo que haga tu App.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Cada actividad de mi aplicación realiza una consulta a la BD para llenar un ListView.  Sobre ese ListView puedo seleccionar un elemento para modificarlo/borrarlo o también añadir uno nuevo.  Eso por ahora es básicamente el funcionamiento de las tres actividades de las que se compone mi aplicación.

Siguiendo tu sugerencia, lo que haré será conectarme a la BD en cada actividad.

Un saludo y gracias.